# How to tell Visual Studio Code about the location of source files of Dart libraries

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

I have this very simple code:

```dart
void main() async
{
  print("Hello");
}
```

when I try to step into the function `print` I get the following message:

> Could not load source 'dart:core/print.dart': <source not available>.

My Visual Studio Code version is:

> 1.32.3
>   a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
>   x64

I added the following to my Visual Studio Code `settings.json`:

```
    "dart.debugSdkLibraries": true,
    "dart.debugExternalLibraries": true,
```

My Dart version:

> Dart VM version: 2.2.0 (Tue Feb 26 15:04:32 2019 +0100) on "windows_x64"

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the Dart VM for a while stopped serving up source code for built-in libraries. This has changed in SDK v2.2.1 so once that reaches stable releases, you won't see this anymore (or if you switch to a dev build, you'll see this sooner).

If you still have problems from v2.2.1, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) and I'll take a look. Thanks!